# UIView is not animating properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

so i'm  trying to move my `UIView` out of frame, but instead of getting out of view it's just **Animating to the center of ViewController** 
My code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 4, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: [], animations: ({

        self.myTextField.center.x = 1300 // just a temporary value
    }), completion: nil)

    print(self.passwordTextField.center.x)//---> 1300
```

anyone knows why is it happening? and how can i fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? When you change the center, it'll obviously change the center, ha.

Comment: you know what it means? 1300? it supposed to set the center of that view to 1300 which means out of frame, and thanks for giving it your thoughts. HA! @LinusGeffarth

Comment: Yeah, so what happens? You should define "centered". Maybe post pictures.

Comment: Using autolayout? Is the outlet properly connected (if it is an outlet)? Try to rather set the `origin.x` to the `view.frame.width`. Thats safer than just setting it to some random number.